Filter and sort data with multiple column & row criteria and match corresponding data to it with flexible return_arrays



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P




1
Product

Shop

2023-S
2023-M

2024-S
2024-M

Type







2


















3







500










4


P-Line_A









Step1





5
Prod_A

shop3

80
2%

500
22%

t1

ColCrit1
ColCrit2
ColCrit3



6
Prod_B

shop2

320
23%

180
60%

t1

Prod_D
shop1
t3



7
Prod_B

shop1

90
8%

300
36%

t2

Prod_G
shop3
t4



8
Prod_C

shop3

500
15%

657
16%

t1


shop4




9
Prod_D

shop1

160
17%

500
15%

t3







10
Prod_D

shop1

500
30%

600
8%

t3

rowCrit





11
Prod_D

shop1

130
4%

300
4%

t3

2024-S





12
Total



1810


3037










13


















14







600




Step2





15







300




l_array
r_array1
r_array2
r_array3


16


P-Line_B









2024-S
Product
Type
Shop


17
Prod_E

shop2

75
10%

450
10%

t1







18
Prod_F

shop4

60
8%

370
4%

t2







19
Prod_F

shop1

500
11%

850
4%

t2

Step3





20
Prod_G

shop3

350
8%

150
15%

t3

Rows
Start




21
Prod_G

shop3

60
47%

600
7%

t4

10
2




22
Prod_G

shop4

90
25%

830
35%

t4







23
Prod_G

shop2

390
9%

325
13%

t1







24
Prod_G

shop3

90
30%

300
9%

t3

Step4





25
Prod_G

shop4

90
5%

300
12%

t3

Product
Type
Shop
2024-S


26
Prod_G

shop4

120
24%

300
24%

t4

Prod_D
t3
shop1
600


27
Prod_G

shop4

135
35%

480
17%

t4

Prod_G
t4
shop3
600


28
Prod_H

shop2

935
27%

230
16%

t1

Prod_D
t3
shop1
500


29
Prod_I

shop3

134
18%

600
42%

t2

Prod_G
t4
shop4
480


30
Total



3029


5785




Prod_D
t3
shop1
300


31












Prod_G
t3
shop3
300


32












Prod_G
t3
shop4
300


33












Prod_G
t4
shop4
300


34












Prod_G
t3
shop3
150


35


















36




















Target
The final Output is Range M26:P34 which is a descending list based on the lookup_array in Cell M16 and multiple column and row filters (Range M6:M8, Range N6:O8, Range O6:O8 and Cell M11) and selected positions in the rank based on Cell M21 and Cell N21.
To get this list the following steps are required: 
(You can also see the steps in the table in Column M so it is easier to follow the instructions)

Define multiple column criteria in Range M6:O6 and a row criteria in Cell M11. These criteria are all AND criteria. After filtering the list it should be sorted descending.
Based on Step1 you will have a descending list fulfilling the column and row criteria. For this list the corresponding values based on ret_array1 in Cell N16, ret_array2  in Cell O16 and ret_array3 in Cell P16 should be added.  (Note: lookup_array = rowCrit --> Cell M16 = Cell M11)
From the list in Step2 only the values that are ranked in positions based on Cell M21 and Cell N21 should be displayed.  In this case the 10 positions after the 1st position.
After Step1-3 in Step4 the final list should appear.


In comparison to the answer in this question I added an additional return_array3 in Cell P16.  I tried to implement this additional array to the formula like this:
=LET(
    _a; COUNTIF(M6:M8;A1:A31)+AND(M6:M8="");
    _b; COUNTIF(N6:N8;C1:C31)+AND(N6:N8="");
    _c; COUNTIF(O6:O8;K1:K31)+AND(O6:O8="");
    _d; CHOOSECOLS(A1:K31;XMATCH(HSTACK(N16;O16;P16;M16);A1:K1));
    _e; SORT(FILTER(HSTACK(_d;FILTER(A1:K31;A1:K1=M11;""));_a*_b*_c;"");3;-1);
    WRAPROWS(TOCOL(INDEX(_e;SEQUENCE(M21;;N21);SEQUENCE(;3));2);3))

However, now the values for 2024-S are not appearing anymore and the sorting is also different:

How do I need to modify the formula to make it work?

Try using the following, this is dynamic :


=LET(
 _a, COUNTIF(M6:M8,A1:A31)+AND(M6:M8=""),
 _b, COUNTIF(N6:N8,C1:C31)+AND(N6:N8=""),
 _c, COUNTIF(O6:O8,K1:K31)+AND(O6:O8=""),
 _d, TOROW(HSTACK(N16,O16,P16,M16),1),
 _e, CHOOSECOLS(A1:K31,XMATCH(_d,A1:K1)),
 _f, COLUMNS(_d),
 _g, SORT(FILTER(HSTACK(_e,FILTER(A1:K31,A1:K1=M11,"")),_a*_b*_c,""),_f+1,-1),
 WRAPROWS(TOCOL(INDEX(_g,SEQUENCE(M21,,N21),SEQUENCE(,_f)),2),_f))


With Headers as well:


=LET(
    _a, COUNTIF(M6:M8,A1:A31)+AND(M6:M8=""),
    _b, COUNTIF(N6:N8,C1:C31)+AND(N6:N8=""),
    _c, COUNTIF(O6:O8,K1:K31)+AND(O6:O8=""),
    _d, TOROW(HSTACK(N16,O16,P16,M16),1),
    _e, CHOOSECOLS(A1:K31,XMATCH(_d,A1:K1)),
    _f, COLUMNS(_d),
    _g, SORT(FILTER(HSTACK(_e,FILTER(A1:K31,A1:K1=M11,"")),_a*_b*_c,""),_f+1,-1),
    VSTACK(_d, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(INDEX(_g,SEQUENCE(M21,,N21),SEQUENCE(,_f)),2),_f)))


Thanks for your answer. Do you also have a solution where the headers are not included in the results?

@Michi just remove the VSTACK() part so remove --> VSTACK(_d,  Updated check the first one!
